# How to pass $_FILE from Page1 to page3 via Page2

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an excel file using PHPExcel. There are 3 file which are involved in this process -
**Page1.php**

```
<table width="100%">
<form  action ="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="uploadexcel">
   <tr>
      <td width="30%">Upload Student-Enquiry File Here:</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="studentfile"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="uploadexcel" value="Upload"></td>
   </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']) || $_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']=="" ) {
   header('location: ./?pid=1&unauth=0');
   exit;
}
if ($action =="uploadexcel"){
     if($uploadexcel="Upload"){
        $inputFileName =$_FILES['studentfile']['tmp_name'];
    $filepath=$_FILES['studentfile']['name'];
    $url = "exam_excel/page3.php";
        header("Location: ".$url);
     }
}
?>
```

**Page3.php** This page actually uploading the excel data to MySQL table and I need that selected excel file to be processed here -

```
<?php session_start();
include("../../includes/constants.inc.php"); //Database configuration File

if(isset($_FILES['studentfile']['tmp_name']))
if(isset($inputFile))
{   
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $inputFileName =$_FILES['studentfile']['tmp_name'];

//Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e){
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": ' . $e->getMessage());
}

//  Get worksheet dimensions
        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
        {
            //  Read a row of data into an array
            $temp=array("");
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
            foreach($rowData[0] as $k=>$v)
            {
                array_push($temp,$v);
            }
            if(!empty($temp[45]) &!empty($temp[46]) )
            {
                $tccase="Yes";
            }
            else
            {
            $tccase="No";
            }
            $q="insert into es_enquiry(eq_submitedon,eq_application_no,eq_class,class_sift,eq_name,eq_sex,eq_dob,age,month,day,blood_g,scat_id,ehandi,e_ews,e_bpl,e_sgc,eq_mothername,father_name,eq_countryid,eq_emailid,office_address,office_phone,resident_phone,dist_from_kv,eq_permaddress,domicile,  no_of_transfer,parent_cate_id,kv_tc_no,kv_tc_date,last_class_cgpa,documents,mother_occu,father_occu,eq_city,eq_state,eq_zip,per_city,per_state,per_zip,per_country,mid_name,last_name,tc_case,eq_from_aca,eq_to_aca,eq_tempaddress,present_country,cam_image) values('".$temp[5]."','".$temp[3]."','".$temp[4]."','".$temp[2]."','".$temp[6]."','".$temp[9]."','".$temp[10]."','".$temp[11]."','".$temp[12]."','".$temp[13]."','".$temp[14]."','".$temp[17]."','".$temp[40]."','".$temp[41]."','".$temp[42]."','".$temp[43]."','".$temp[20]."','".$temp[18]."','".$temp[15]."','".$temp[16]."','".$temp[22]."','".$temp[23]."','".$temp[29]."','".$temp[36]."','".$temp[30]."','".$temp[39]."','".$temp[38]."','".$temp[37]."','".$temp[45]."','".$temp[46]."','".$temp[44]."','".$temp[47]."','".$temp[21]."','".$temp[19]."','".$temp[25]."','".$temp[26]."','".$temp[28]."','".$temp[31]."','".$temp[32]."','".$temp[35]."','".$temp[33]."','".$temp[7]."','".$temp[8]."','".$tccase."','".$temp[49]."','".$temp[50]."','".$temp[24]."','".$temp[27]."','".$temp[8]."')";
            mysql_query($q)or die(mysql_error());
            unset($temp);
        }
        echo "Your data inserted successfully";
}
else
{
echo "Select Excel FIle";
}
?>
```

If directly use Page3.php from Page1.php using Action="Page3.php" works fine but I don't access directly without authentication. I tried various way to get the selected file name on Page3.php but getting Temp name. I tried by passing the temp_name via URL like this $url = "exam_excel/page3.php?inputFile=".$inputFileName; and receiving it $filename=$_GET['inputFile']; and then I tried to use this variable in place of inputFileName on page3.php but failed.

Give some suggestion/guidance on this issue

Answer (score 0):

When a file upload is passed to a PHP page, you need to deal with that file immediately, either by moving it to a more permanent storage location or by processing its contents. You can't pass it back to the user, as there is no way to prefill an `<input type=file>`, and expecting the user to upload a potentially large file a second time is unreasonable. If you do not do anything with the uploaded file, PHP will destroy it at the end of the request, and it's gone.